# How to search through an array of Object with varying search parameters in VueJs3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a search function, which looks at Objects and displays results, based on if there is a match with the chosen search parameter (ID, NAME).

This works fine via searching with an ID, but when I attempt to use name, it returns undefined, and I can't see why ID can be succesfully returned, but name cannot.

Store:

```
export const useCaseFileStore = defineStore('caseFile', {
    state: () => ({
        matchingCaseFiles: [],
        searchMethod: null,
        caseFiles: [{
            name: 'John Cramer',
            id: 1111,
            title: 'test Files'
        },
        {
            name: 'John Cramer',
            id: 11212,
            title: 'test fileTwo'
        }
        ],
        activeCaseFile: [{
            name: null,
            id: null,
            title: null
        },],
    }),
  actions: {
    searchByCf(searchQuery) {
        this.activeCaseFile = searchQuery;
    },

getters: { 
    activeCaseFiles: (state) => {
        return state.caseFiles.find(cf => cf.id === state.activeCaseFile);
    },
},
```

Search Component:

```
<input
   placeholder="Type here to start a search and press ENTER"
   class="input w-full input-bordered input-sm"
   v-model="searchInput"
  />
  
 const searchInput = ref(0);

 watch(searchInput, async (newVal) => {
  store.searchByCf(newVal);
});
```

Comment: is `activeCaseFile` object or an array?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Object

Comment: `activeCaseFile` is an array ( as shown in the store), I'm not sure where is search field value you search by?

Comment: @Mina I've updated with the relevant code, however logging activeCaseFile with typeof returns me an object.

Comment: @seanberlin Yes,`typeof []` is equal to `object`, to check if it's array or not `Array.isArray(value)`

Comment: Do you want search with casesensative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activeCaseFile` Shouldn't be an array it should be an empty string on initial load, as it updates with the input value.

```
 activeCaseFile: ''
```

Also, you need to use `filter` method not `find` method to return all items that match the input value.

If you want the search without casesensitive

```
activeCaseFiles: (state) => {
    const inputValueAsLowerCase = state.activeCaseFile.toLowerCase()
    return state.caseFiles.find(cf => 
 inputValueAsLowerCase.includes(cf.id) || 
 inputValueAsLowerCase.includes(cf.name.toLowerCase() ||
 inputValueAsLowerCase.includes(cf.title.toLowerCase())));
},
```

If not just remove `toLowerCase()` method.

Comment: Great solution, one query I have though is that if for example, I have another Object, with the ID of '111112', it will return me that object, and the first object with an ID of 11111, is there a better way to filter for only exact matches within this function?

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you want exact the same id use `inputValueAsLowerCase === cf.id` instead of `inputValueAsLowerCase.includes(cf.id)`